# "cannot attach to process due to System Integrity Protection" error seen when trying to run perl script in Xcode

Tags: xcode, perl

I have OS sierra 12.12.3
I am trying to run a perl script in Xcode but i get the following error:
Message from debugger: cannot attach to process due to System Integrity Protection

I am able to run C code in Xcode without getting any such errors though. Why would there be any issues with running a simple perl script in xcode ? what are the security implications?
Any way to work around this without disabling sip?

Comment: Can you execute the Xcode app *without* using the debugger?  Perhaps SIP will allow the app to call the Perl script, but it just won't allow Xcode to attach to it for debugging.

Comment: this might be a solution. I am not sure how to disable the debugger though. can you advise on that? by the way i am not really running an "app". I am just trying to run a simple perl script in Xcode

Comment: I'm more a Visual Studio guy, don't really know Xcode itself.  But the idea should be the same.  You should be able to compile your Xcode project into a Mac OS app.  When running the app in Finder, Xcode will no longer be involved.  That might work.  Or, if you're just using Xcode to run ONLY a Perl script (not inside a real Mac OS app), try running directly from Terminal.  Or try a Perl IDE, like Komodo.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Select Target from Xcode toolbar.

[image]

Step 2: Click on `Edit Scheme`

[image]

Step 3: Uncheck as indicated.

[image]